# PotPlayer: how to disable internet communication?

Tags: windows-7, daum-pot-player

According to techsupportalert.com, best free Media Player is PotPlayer.

https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-windows-media-player-replacement.htm

I've been trying PotPlayer for a while and it's quite good.

The only problem is it's keep trying to access the following sites every time I bring this apps up.

```
http://track.tiara.daum.net:443
http://get.daum.net/PotPlayer/v4/HostDefEng.sig
http://t1.daumcdn.net/potplayer/PotPlayer/v4/MajorVersionEng.sig
http://potplayertv.daum.net/checksvc
```

Initially, I thought this because of the automatic updates.

http://ccm.net/faq/25152-daum-potplayer-disable-automatic-updates

Then, I disabled it. However, it still attempt to do the same connection every time I restart PotPlayer.

[image]

Please let me know how to block this access permanently on Windows client.

I don't want PotPlayer to make a internet connection at all.

Comment: Stick those websites in your host file as `127.0.0.1` and `::1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use OneClickFirewall app https://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.1841

Just install it, and find your PotPlayerMini.exe location. Usually here

> C:\Program Files (x86)\DAUM\PotPlayer

After that right click PotPlayerMini.exe, choose "Block Internet Access"

[image]